# My Google Scholar profile is public but it does not appear in Google's search result. How can I fix this problem?

Tags: google-scholar

My Google Scholar profile is public but it does not appear in Google's search result. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the link to my Google Scholar profile:

https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=U81fBHYAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao

Comment: When did you make the profile? It can take some time to appear in the results.

Comment: Hi, I made it around 10 days ago.

Comment: Ok, that should be more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

Read about the [page rank algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) of Google.

The same problem was happening to me. Then I linked my google scholar's page to my homepage (institute one). Now it appears at the top in the google search results.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you very much.